I am getting an Access Violation on returning through a recursive routine
I am building a database of keywords which I am extracting from text files. The text files can reference other text files using the keyword 'include'.
I am using these data structures:

ItemRecord: carries details of a keyword in a file, its position etc.

FileTree: carries arrays of all the ItemRecords for a specific text file

Pages: array of FileTrees for all the files referenced from the Root text.


This is the primary recursion code:
Const
  Items: array [0..1] of string = ('Includes','Variables');

function RecurseKeywords(pFileName: String; PageIdx: Integer; L1Index: Integer = 0): Integer;
Var
  i,z, idx, idy, idz,k: Integer;
  ChildCtr: Integer;
  ActMem: TStringList;
  s,t:string;

  function GetItems(Text: String; Category: TCategory):string;
  Var
    RegEx: TRegex;
    Match: TMatch;
  begin
    case Category of
      caIncludes:
        Match := Regex.Match(Text, '^\s*Include\s+"([0-9a-z_\-\\ :]+[\.inc|\.bas]+)"',[roignorecase]);
      caVariables:
        Match := Regex.Match(Text,'^\s*Dim\s+([a-z_#][0-9a-z_#]+)(?:_0-9a-z)*(\s+as\s+(bit|byte|word|dword|float|sbyte|sword|sdword|Long|slong|double|string|pin))',[roignorecase]);
    end;
    if match.Success then
      result := match.Groups[1].Value
    else
      result := '';
  end;

begin
  Result := 0;
  with Pages[PageIdx] do
    if fileExists(pFileName) then begin
      ActMem := TStringList.Create;
      ActMem.LoadFromFile(pFileName);
      idz := L1Index;    // Set Key to first item in the level 1 list
      for idy := 0 to High(Items) do begin   // scan through all items
        ChildCtr := 0;
        for idx := 0 to ActMem.Count -1 do begin
          t := trimLeft(ActMem[idx]);   // remove spaces and skip empty lines.
          if (t <> '') and (t[1] <> #39) and (t[1] <> #59) then begin
            s := GetItems(t, TCategory(idy));
            if s > '' then with Pages[PageIdx] do begin
              if (High(L0CodeData) = -1)                            // if no L0 data or
              or (L0CodeData[High(L0CodeData)].RecType<>TCategory(idy)) then   // L0 Record type <> to Item type
                SetLength(L0CodeData,Length(L0CodeData)+1);         // Create new L0 entry
              with L0CodeData[High(L0CodeData)] do begin
                RecType := TCategory(idy);
                Caption := Items[idy];
                ImageIndex := 0;
                lineNo := Idx;
                Key := idz;
              end;

              SetLength(L1CodeData, Length(L1CodeData)+ 1);
              with L1CodeData[High(L1CodeData)] do begin   // Populate the L1 Record
                RecType := TCategory(idy);
                Caption := s;
                ImageIndex := idy+3;
                LineNo := idx;
                case RecType of
                  caIncludes:
                    if FileExists(sourcepath+s) then begin
                      ImageIndex := 4;
                      SetLength(Pages, Length(Pages)+1);
                      Key := High(Pages);
                      Caption := s;
                      ChildCount := RecurseKeywords(SourcePath+s,key);
                    end;
                  caVariables:
                end;
                ChildCount := 0;
                Inc(ChildCtr);
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        idz := Idz + ChildCtr;
        if ChildCtr > 0 then
          Pages[PageIdx].L0CodeData[High(L0CodeData)].ChildCount := ChildCtr;
        Form1.SaveToFile;
      end;
      ActMem.Free;
      result := Length(Pages[PageIdx].L0CodeData);
    end;
end;

When the recursion has returned to the top level file and moves on from includes to other keyword types, I get an Access Violation.  At that point, the database is fully built with the exception of keywords beyond include keyword in the top level file. When I inspect the contents of the arrays up to the AV, they all look correct.
I have produced a simple app to demonstrate this, it runs to 210 lines. I understand one is not supposed to upload apps however small.
Can anyone explain what is happening, and what I need to do to prevent the AV?

The first thing I would do is remove all the "with" statements and then debug in your normal fashion.

On which line does the AV happen? Maybe you also need to enable range and overflow check in the compiler settings.

@JohnTaylor I did remove all the with statments and explicitly referenced everything but the same error occired.

@DelphiCoder The AV occurs at 7th line up from bottom 'Pages[PageIdx].L0CodeData[High(L0CodeData)].ChildCount := ChildCtr;'

@JohnBarrat Try changing High(L0CodeData) to High(Pages[PageIdx].L0CodeData) in that line. With all the withs, maybe you are accessing the wrong L0CodeData in that High expression.

@RemyLebeau  THank you, that seems to have solved it.  I don't understand why it only failed when reaching the top level, it should have failed on the deeper recursions as well.

@JohnBarrat hard to say without a [mcve] that people can copy/paste and step through in their debugger. Which you should be doing as well...

The top tip you need is that you should enable range checking which would have told you what was happening immediately, rather than waiting for intermittent AVs
